# What exception to throw on encountering unexpected text?

Tags: java, exception

I'm reading through an XML file and at a certain position I am expecting (as part of the contract) to read `<offset>nnnn</offset>` (where nnnn is a number). I have already checked that it is valid, well-formed XML. But if it does not say `<format>` at that point then it is breaking the contract and I want to throw an exception. What pre-existing Java exception class is the most appropriate one to throw in this case?

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException.`

Comment: I was thinking of `IllegalArgumentException` but then I'm not really passing an argument to a method, so "illegal argument" would be a misnomer. @ShanuGupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers given so far. I've just thought of my own answer: `InputMismatchException`. Advantage: its name describes exactly what the problem is. Disadvantage: its Javadoc says it is thrown by a `Scanner`, which is not what I'm using. Nevertheless, it does seem to be an appropriate choice. If anyone thinks this is not an appropriate exception class to use, please comment.

Comment: I wouldn't class this as suitable - it's specifically for use by a `Scanner`. If you really want to broaden the search out you could use `NoSuchElementException`, but in all honesty I'd still recommend going with one of the "simple" built in exceptions, and putting any additional clarification you feel you may need in the exception text.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise structuring the code so that the XML file / XML content (depending on what makes the most sense) is passed to a method as an argument, then throw `IllegalArgumentException` if the XML file doesn't have the required elements.

You could potentially also use `InvalidStateException`, if the XML is more internal to the application and/or it would fit better than `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have already checked that it is valid, well-formed XML.

1) The XML would not be valid against a XSD that define that the `<offset>` element has to contain a number.

2) If under the hood you use SAX, You could throw `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException`.
That is what is actually thrown as an XSD validation fails ([`javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html#validate-javax.xml.transform.Source-)).

Its javadoc states :

> Encapsulate an XML parse error or warning.

So the client could get something like :

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value 'xxx' of
>   element 'offset' is not valid.  A number is expected

Note that `IllegalArgumentException` is a possibility but I find it a little too broad.